# JavaScript How to detect if selection is part of element

Tags: javascript

I have a small WYSIWYG editor built in JavaScript.

It is working by the getrange methode:

```
const range = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
const oldConent = document.createTextNode(range.toString());
const newElement = document.createElement('span');
// do some style changes
newElement.append(oldConent);
range.insertNode(ulList);
```

The issue is that I can now adjust everything on the page.

How to limit the functionality on a selection from a specific div?

**What I tried**

I tried to avoid other selection by a simple if condition:

```
// editable div contains the id 'textField'
if (range.endContainer.parentElement.id === 'textField') { ... }
```

But it is only working when the selection is not part of another element.

Comment: Are you using `contenteditable`?

Comment: yes. contenteditable is enabled on the div with id 'textfield'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your range will have a [**range.commonAncestorContainer**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Range/commonAncestorContainer) property that points to the deepest node that contains the start and end Nodes of the range. You can check if that node is the specific div you want or at least a child node of that div.

Your code will look something like

```
const range = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
  const textField = document.getElementById("textField");
  if (
    range.commonAncestorContainer.isSameNode(textField) ||
    textField.contains(range.commonAncestorContainer)
  ) {
    const oldConent = document.createTextNode(range.toString());
    const newElement = document.createElement('span');
    // do some style changes
    newElement.append(oldConent);
    range.insertNode(ulList);
  }
```